# Why does Quarkus @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) automatically add the array wrapper and comma to values?

Tags: java, json, quarkus, media-type, smallrye

I have a POST Rest API developed using Quarkus with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` this method returns the list of customers asynchronously. But the problem is that it adds the additional array wrapper and comma separation, which is not required. Everything works fine when used with `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` but since my response is of JSON type I want to keep `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. Is there anyway to avoid the modification to response?

For example following is the response I am getting with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`. You can see it adds unwanted commas and arrays within my response:

```
[
  {
  "isA": "customerDocument",
  "createdOn": "2022-10-10T12:29:43",
  "customerBody": {
    "customerList": [,
      {
        "name": "Batman",
        "age": 45,
        "city": "gotham"
      },
      {
        "name": "superman",
        "age": 50,
        "city": "moon"
      },
    ]
  }
}]
```

The response I would like is correctly achievable with `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`:

```
{
  "isA": "customerDocument",
  "createdOn": "2022-10-10T12:29:43",
  "customerBody": {
    "customerList": [
      {
        "name": "Batman",
        "age": 45,
        "city": "gotham"
      },
      {
        "name": "superman",
        "age": 50,
        "city": "moon"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I use text/plain, everything works fine. Is there something that I can modify to avoid the addition of array wrapper and comma when using with `application/json`?

I believe this is happening because I am generating the elements in `customerList` asynchronously using the `SmallRye Mutin Multi<String>`. Can someone please provide some suggestion?

The following is the Quarkus Rest API for GET requests:

```
  @Path("/testData")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Multi <String> test() throws IOException {
      return Multi.createFrom().items(IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TestJSON.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: My understanding is that when you use application/json, on your endpoint method's, in the background, Quarkus uses a serializer (of your choosing) to serialize your methods return objects for you. If you are generating JSON formatted strings (already prepared for serialization) prior to your endpoint method's output, the Quarkus serializer might take the already serialized output and try to serialize it again, which would result in an array wrapping your output like you have above.

Comment: If you post some code or an MWE it should be a simple enough fix. Additionally, If you want the method to return a single payload (with an inner list) make sure the endpoint method itself returns a Uni. A multi will produce multiple things, thus you'd get serialized to an array.

Comment: So short version:

1. Make sure your endpoint returns a Uni of whatever type you want.
2. Make sure your type is not "String", it should be whatever your actual object payload is.

Comment: @geoand Please find the code sample provided at the end of the question.

Comment: @TheFunk Thanks for the response, I have provided the sample code. Isn't there any way to achieve this while using `Multi`? Because my depending application always returns `Multi` so would like to keep it as it is.